# htaccess [F] doesn't seem to work

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to forbid access to anything wordpress related

The below doesn't work and just fires a 404:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*wp-.*)$ - [L,F]
```

Although if I do it like so, everything's fine:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*wp-.*)$ whatever [L,R]
```

EDIT: checking via http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ shows no issues.

EDIT 2: I can't see how is this a duplicate of the mod_rewrite tut, clearly I have checked with it and unfortunately had found no solution there.

EDIT 3: I was able to confirm that it works on my local VM and other staging servers, is there a way to debug it on the production server?

EDIT 4: The fix was provided in the comments, clearly showing that the solution was not mentioned in the "duplicate" post but was related to the default 403 error page missing

Comment: The above could be explained with a server (miss)configuration, or putting the directives in the wrong place in your `.htaccess` file. But, a _redirect_ shouldn't be "fine" either? (If you were to literally redirect to "whatever" it would surely break?!)

Comment: You are correct, but redirects work, "whatever" is just an example, all redirects work to either existing or non-existent pages.

Comment: I was able to confirm that it works on my local VM and other staging servers, is there a way to debug it on the production server?

Comment: Try setting `ErrorDocument default` in your `.htaccess` file. Any difference?

Comment: I'm getting a 500 with it

Comment: from the log: ErrorDocument takes two arguments, ErrorDocument Apache configuration directive

Comment: Sorry, `ErrorDocument 403 default`.

Comment: @w3dk Perfect! Thanks a ton, that fixed it, feel free to add it as the answer!

Comment: If that works then it suggests that a custom `ErrorDocument` has been defined in the server config which is overriding the default 403 with a 404 status! If this is your own server then it should be "fixed" in the server config. However, I have also seen this on some shared servers (not sure why, other than it possibly being in error?).

Comment: Yes I figured that it tried to get the 403.shtml page but since that didn't exist it carried on to a 404. So your solution is absolutely correct. Is the question closed due to it being flagged as a duplicate?

Comment: "but since that didn't exist it carried on to a 404" - That might be related. However, normally, if a defined ErrorDocument does not exist, Apache will generate a "system" error document and still return the correct status code (ie. a 403).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when an `ErrorDocument` is defined in the server config that overrides the HTTP status that would otherwise be returned for that particular error. In this case, an `ErrorDocument` might be defined for a 403 status, but explicitly returns a 404 HTTP status code instead.

Ordinarily, you would resolve this at source in the server config, however, you can reset the error document back to its default (or set your own custom `ErrorDocument`) in `.htaccess`. For example:

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
```

I have seen a similar (apparent) misconfiguration on some shared servers, where overriding in `.htaccess` is the only option.

> ...it tried to get the `403.shtml` page but since that didn't exist it carried on to a 404.

This perhaps sounds plausible, however, it doesn't "normally" work like that. Normally, if the defined custom error document does not exist, Apache responds with a "system generated" error document and still sets the correct HTTP status code.

(The "system generated" error document is *slightly* different to the "default" error document you would normally see.)